# Numpy: Iterative combination of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The following code is intended to iteratively construct a new numpy base on the old one

```
prv = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])

results = []
for i in prv:
    results.append(calc_something(i))

results = np.reshape(np.array(results), (prv.shape[0], 1))

combined = np.hstack((prv, results))
```

The problem is that it produces the following result:

```
[[1 2 array([6, 7, 3])]
 [3 4 array([3])]
 [5 6 array([9, 7])]]
```

While the expected result is:

```
[[1,2,6],
 [1,2,7],
 [1,2,3],
 [3,4,3],
 [5,6,9],
 [5,6,7]]
```

For simplicity we assume that the function `calc_something(i)` returns the values as follows

```
def calc_something(i):
    if i[0] == 1:
        b = np.array([6,7,3])
        return b
    if i[0] == 3:
        b = np.array([3])
        return b
    if i[0] == 5:
        b = np.array([9,7])
        return b
```

What is needs to be changed to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `np.column_stack` result of `np.repeat` along zero axis together with concatenation of results of `calc_something()`

```
prv = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]) 
results = [calc_something(i) for i in prv[:, 0].tolist()]
repeats = [len(n) for n in results]
leftside = np.repeat(prv, repeats, axis=0)
rightside = np.concatenate(results)
output = np.column_stack([leftside, rightside])
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 6],
       [1, 2, 7],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 3],
       [5, 6, 9],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your current logic structure, this solution uses the `np.column_stack()` function to append the returned `calc()` function values to an extended array.

The `calc` function, with minor tweaks:

```
def calc(i):
    if i[0] == 1:
        b = np.array([6, 7, 3])
    elif i[0] == 3:
        b = np.array([3])
    elif i[0] == 5:
        b = np.array([9, 7])
    return b
```

Example code:

```
prv = np.arange(1, 7).reshape(-1, 2)
result = np.array((), dtype=int)

for i in prv:
    b = calc(i)
    c = np.column_stack((np.tile(i, b.size).reshape(-1, i.size), b))
    result = np.append(result, c)
    
r = result.reshape(-1, 3)
```

Output:

```
arrray([[1, 2, 6],
        [1, 2, 7],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [3, 4, 3],
        [5, 6, 9],
        [5, 6, 7]])
```

General comments:

The `calc` function can be removed all-together and replaced with a simple `dict`, using the array value [1, 3, 5] and the returned array, as key/value pairs. Then, perform a simple `dict.get()` function rather than the `calc` function call.